# How to extract files using the dd command?

Tags: filesystem, dd, tail

I'm trying to extract a squashfs file from a .bin

What I did so far:

I used binwalk to locate the pointers: `binwalk data.bin`

```
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
512           0x200           LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x6D, dictionary 
                              size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 3420708 bytes
1134468       0x114F84        Squashfs filesystem, little endian, version 4.0, 
                              compression:xz, size: 13089146 bytes, 2102 inodes, 
                              blocksize: 262144 bytes, created: 2016-10-28 05:42:31`
```

How can I extract only the squashfs filesystem using `dd` or `tail`, so I can later get the content its by using the `unsquashfs` command.

Thanks

Comment: `dd if=data.bin of=somewhat ibs=4 skip=283617`. `skip`means to skip n input blocks, each of size 4 Bytes (`ìbs=4`). This could be very slow, as the blocks have to be very small (4 Bytes) for skip to work.

Comment: the `skip=283617` is a wrong value I guess, here what I get after `unsquashfs output.squashfs` : `Can't find a SQUASHFS superblock on output.squashfs`

Comment: So I may be mistaken what the number "1134468" (=4*283617) in the binwalk output says. Maybe you can try `binwalk -e` to extract?

Comment: @ridgy what can I say.. Thank you so much. I wasn't looking for that kind of files only for some specific bytes but anyway I can start from that ;)